# Discord.js Set position to a text channel

Tags: discord.js

I have a problem with discord.js: I want to set a position to a channel :

```
const chanName = message.channel.name;
    let categoryId = message.channel.parentID
    let position = message.channel.position
    console.dir(position)
    const catego = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id == categoryId && c.type == "category")
    message.channel.delete().catch();
    
    const chan = message.guild.channels.create(chanName, {type: 'text'}).then((channel) => channel.setParent(catego) && channel.setPosition(position) && channel.send(`Succesfully nuked \`${chanName}\`\nhttps://imgur.com/LIyGeCR`))
    chan
```

but when i execute the command the channel is not set at the position.

I would also like to save the permissions to put them back after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the `then` callback:

```js
channel.setParent(catego) && channel.setPosition(position) && channel.send(`Succesfully nuked \`${chanName}\`\nhttps://imgur.com/LIyGeCR`)
```

[`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) is the logical AND operator. `channels.setParent(catego)` returns a `Promise`, which is truthy because it is an object. Because `&&` short-circuits, it does not evaluate the other expressions `channel.setPosition(...)` and `channel.send(...)` because the expression will evaluate to that `Promise` regardless.

You want to execute multiple statements instead:

```js
const chan = message.guild.channels.create(chanName, {type: 'text'}).then(channel => {
  channel.setParent(catego)
  channel.setPosition(position)
  channel.send(`Succesfully nuked \`${chanName}\`\nhttps://imgur.com/LIyGeCR`)
})
```

It's important to remember that `channel => ...` is just an ordinary [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and the following are all equivalent:

```js
const f1 = channel => channel.setParent(catego)
const f2 = channel => {
  return channel.setParent(catego)
}
const f3 = function (channel) {
  return channel.setParent(catego)
}
function f4(channel) {
  return channel.setParent(catego)
}
```

However, in this case, you can set the parent and position of the channel while creating it:

```js
const chan = message.guild.channels.create(chanName, {
  type: 'text',
  parent: catego,
  position
})
  .then(channel =>
    channel.send(`Succesfully nuked \`${chanName}\`\nhttps://imgur.com/LIyGeCR`)
  )
```

You can see the other options in [the documentation for `GuildChannelManager#create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create).

Comment: Ty for help but same problem, the channel don't go to his position. I think it's because when the channel is deleted the position is get again so the chan is not at the good position